# What's the difference between .post() , .create() and perform_create() in views.py and .create() in serializers.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm confused with `.post()` and `.create()` and `perform_create()` in `views.py` and `.create()` in `serializers.py`
seems like `.create()` in `serializers.py` get the `validated_data`, so it can not check `serializer.is_valid`

Here is the `serializers.py`:

```
class PostListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'publish',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("-------------------")
        print("5555555 - create", validated_data)
        return Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

And if my code is :

**views.py**

```
class TestPostListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = PostListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            # deal with serializer.errors
            return Response({'[post]custome error 1 !!!!!!!!!'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            print("[post]- serializer.validated_data ", serializer.validated_data)
            serializer.save()
        return Response({'[post]Create success'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

the process will go `.post()` in `views.py` --> `.create()` in `serializers.py`  --> `Response` to client

If my views.py use:

```
class TestPostListAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer

    # def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     serializer = PostListSerializer(data=request.data)
    #     if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
    #         # deal with serializer.errors
    #         return Response({'[post]custome error 1 !!!!!!!!!'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    #     else:
    #         print("[post]- serializer.validated_data ", serializer.validated_data)
    #         serializer.save()
    #     return Response({'[post]Create success'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        print("44444-1 perform_create ", serializer)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            print("44444-3 serializer.is_valid() ", serializer.is_valid())
            return Response({'custome error!!!!!!!!!'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            print("44444-7 serializer.validated_data ", serializer.validated_data)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response({ 'Create success'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print("1111-1 perform_create ", serializer)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            print("1111-3 serializer.is_valid() ", serializer.is_valid())
            return Response({'custome error!!!!!!!!!'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            print("1111-7 serializer.validated_data ", serializer.validated_data)
        user = User.objects.filter(id=8)
        serializer.save(user=user.first())
        print("1111-8 perform_create ")
```

the process is `.create()` in `views.py` --> `.perform_create()` in `views.py` --> `.create()` in `serializers.py` --> `Response` to client

Both can work!
And I found if I post invalid data, the process will not go to `.perform_create()`  part even I comment the `.create()` part, so seems like `.perform_create()` can not check 
`serializer.is_valid()`,neither

So What's the difference between `.post()` and `.create()` in `views.py`  , should I just use `.post()` or should I use `.create()` plus `.perform_create()`
I want to know because I have to use custome response message like `{'custome error!!!!!!!!!'}` , 
but I'm confused with their effect, where should I put the logic

Answer (score 2):

From the docs about `perform_create` hook and others:

> These hooks are particularly useful for setting attributes that are
>   implicit in the request, but **are not part of the request data**. For
>   instance, you might set an attribute on the object based on the
>   request user, or based on a URL keyword argument.